# Calculating Inventory running quantity/value & moving average unit cost

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

Any help to the following problem I have will be appreciated, thank you.
I am trying to perform some retrospective costings on stock inventory and failing to realise my results… I have tried various window functions (lead/Lag/row_number) etc along with multiple ctes and also First_Value….but have failed miserably….so hopefully your thoughts may get me where I want to be.

MS SQL SERVER 2019

This is what I have:

| tId | tType | tcode | tDate | tQty | tValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PO_IN | 456 | 20210901 | 200 | 3654.00 |
| 2 | SO_OUT | 456 | 20210903 | -155 |  |
| 3 | SO_OUT | 456 | 20210904 | -15 |  |
| 4 | PO_IN | 456 | 20210905 | 150 | 3257.00 |
| 5 | SO_OUT | 456 | 20210906 | -120 |  |
| 6 | SO_OUT | 456 | 20210907 | -10 |  |
| 7 | FIN_ADJ | 456 | 20210908 | 0 | -75.00 |
| 8 | SO_OUT | 456 | 20210909 | -20 |  |
| 9 | PO_IN | 456 | 20210902 | 5 | 0.00 |
| 10 | SO_OUT | 456 | 20210910 | -35 |  |

This is what I wish to achieve:

| tId | tType | tcode | tDate | tQty | tValue | Run_Qty | Run_Value | avg_cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PO_IN | 456 | 20210901 | 200 | 3654.00 | 200 | 3654.00 | 18.27 |
| 2 | SO_OUT | 456 | 20210903 | -155 |  | 45 | 822.15 | 18.27 |
| 3 | SO_OUT | 456 | 20210904 | -15 |  | 30 | 548.10 | 18.27 |
| 4 | PO_IN | 456 | 20210905 | 150 | 3257.00 | 180 | 3805.10 | 21.14 |
| 5 | SO_OUT | 456 | 20210906 | -120 |  | 60 | 1268.37 | 21.14 |
| 6 | SO_OUT | 456 | 20210907 | -10 |  | 50 | 1056.97 | 21.14 |
| 7 | FIN_ADJ | 456 | 20210908 | 0 | -75.00 | 50 | 981.97 | 19.64 |
| 8 | SO_OUT | 456 | 20210909 | -20 |  | 30 | 589.18 | 19.64 |
| 9 | PO_IN | 456 | 20210902 | 5 | 0.00 | 35 | 589.18 | 16.83 |
| 10 | SO_OUT | 456 | 20210910 | -35 |  | 0 | 0.00 |  |

PO_IN  have a positive tqty and a positive or zero tvalue.  This can be used to create/ adjust the moving avg cost per unit.

SO-OUT are negative tqty and have NULL tValue and decrement the running qty column and decrement the running value column by the tqty * the previous row avg cost

FIN_ADJ are tValue only and can be positive/negative.

the order of processing required is by tid and not tDate.

If I can get this to output the correct closing qty/value and the correct avg cost per row, I can then move onto the next step of analysis.

Thanks

EDIT....real world tables will have 100K+ rows

Some initial setup code

```
CREATE TABLE tst_Inv(
   tId    INT  NOT NULL
  ,tType  VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
  ,tcode  INT  NOT NULL
  ,tDate  DATE  NOT NULL
  ,tQty   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,tValue NUMERIC(7,2)
);
INSERT INTO tst_Inv(tId,tType,tcode,tDate,tQty,tValue) VALUES
 (1,'PO_IN',456,'20210901',200,3654.00),(2,'SO_OUT',456,'20210903',-155,NULL),(3,'SO_OUT',456,'20210904',-15,NULL)
,(4,'PO_IN',456,'20210905',150,3257.00),(5,'SO_OUT',456,'20210906',-120,NULL),(6,'SO_OUT',456,'20210907',-10,NULL)
,(7,'FIN_ADJ',456,'20210908',0,-75.00),(8,'SO_OUT',456,'20210909',-20,NULL),(9,'PO_IN',456,'20210902',5,0.00)
,(10,'SO_OUT',456,'20210910',-35,NULL);

SELECT * FROM tst_Inv
```

Comment: Will running value and avg cost be calculated from the first occurance of PO_IN if first row isn't PO_IN?

Comment: @Rahul Biswas    yes...for this exercise the first occurrence will be always be a PO_IN.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using CTE

```
;WITH xQ
AS
(
    SELECT tId,tType, tcode, tDate, tQty, tValue , 
        tQty AS Run_Qty, 
        CAST (tValue AS NUMERIC(7,2)) AS Run_Value , 
        tValue / tQty AS Avg_Cost
    FROM tst_Inv
    WHERE tId = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT tId,tType, tcode, tDate, tQty, tValue ,
        xB.Run_Qty,
        xB.Run_Value,
        CASE WHEN xB.Run_Qty = 0 THEN NULL ELSE xB.Run_Value / xB.Run_Qty END AS Avg_Cost  
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT tId,tType, tcode, tDate, tQty, tValue,
            Run_Qty,            
            CAST(
                CASE xA.tType
                    WHEN 'PO_IN' THEN xA.tValue + xA.Run_Value
                    WHEN 'FIN_ADJ' THEN xA.tValue + xA.Run_Value
                    ELSE xA.Run_Qty * xA.Avg_Cost
                END
            AS NUMERIC(7,2)) AS Run_Value,
            xA.Avg_Cost 
        FROM
        (
            SELECT tst_Inv.* , 
                tst_Inv.tQty + xQ.Run_Qty AS Run_Qty,
                xQ.Run_Value,
                xQ.Avg_Cost
            FROM tst_Inv
            INNER JOIN xQ ON (tst_Inv.tId -1) = xQ.tId
            
        ) AS xA
    ) AS xB
)

SELECT * FROM xQ
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Whilst it does produce the correct result, the recursion is inefficient when run on full test tables  (100K + rows)